# Execute async functions in JS interpreter after completion of the previous one in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, interpreter

I am using [JS interpreter](https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/docs.html), I am passing the code to be executed to the interpreter in the function `runMyCode()` I would like the async functions (`moveForward()`) to be called one after another, i.e execute the next function only on completion of the previous one.

In the below for loop, the `moveForward()` will be called 5 times, I would like the subsequent `moveForward()` functions to be called on completion of the previous one. I see that all the functions are called without waiting for the completion. How I can use async/await or Promises while using [JS interpreter](https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/docs.html) or is there any other way.

Here is my React Code:

```js
  var code = '
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
      moveForward();
    }
  '

  function moveForwardFunction() {
    // this function will take time to execute
  }

  var initFunc = function (interpreter, globalObject) {
    var wrapper = function alert(text) {
      return window.alert(text);
    };
    interpreter.setProperty(
      globalObject,
      "alert",
      interpreter.createNativeFunction(wrapper)
    );
    var wrapper = function moveForward() {
      return moveForwardFunction();
    };
    interpreter.setProperty(
      globalObject,
      "moveForward",
      interpreter.createNativeFunction(wrapper)
    );
  };

  var myInterpreter;

  function nextStep() {
    var stack = myInterpreter.getStateStack();
    if (stack.length) {
      var node = stack[stack.length - 1].node;
    }
    if (myInterpreter.step()) {
      nextStep();
    }
  }

  function runMyCode() {
    myInterpreter = new Interpreter(code, initFunc);
  }
```